# Missing Elements in HTTP Request - Null or Empty?

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I have a HTTP Request `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` that is passing in a value to be used in some code being handled in a Java web service using JAX-RS.  The POST function in Java is consuming `application/json`.  There are two possible values to be passed into the request, call one `X` and the other `Y`, assume both are Strings.  The request requires **at least** one of the two possible values to be considered 'valid'.

When the request comes in, if `X` is provided and `Y` is left out of the request entirely, what is the proper way to check to see if `Y` is there?  Would you check to see if `Y.isEmpty()` or `Y == null`?  Providing `X` doesn't guarantee `Y` is present, and vice versa.

Comment: Are you talking in context of the Servlet API? I.e. you're talking about `ServletRequest#getParameter()` and so on? Please clarify/tag at least the involved API. There's namely no such thing in standard Java SE API.

Comment: updated the question with more info.  it is a java web service utilizing JAX-RS, and the specific function is consuming JSON

Comment: In future questions involving `javax.servlet.*` API, please use `[servlets]` tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a parameter is not specified at all like so,

```
http://example.com/context/servlet?x=foo
```

then it will return `null`:

```
String x = request.getParameter("x"); // "foo"
String y = request.getParameter("y"); // null
```

If a parameter is specified, but does not have a value like so,

```
http://example.com/context/servlet?x=foo&y
```

then it will return an empty string:

```
String x = request.getParameter("x"); // "foo"
String y = request.getParameter("y"); // ""
```

Makes sense, right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this answer is exactly what I needed.  Thanks again and I'll remember the servlets tag in the future. (will accept when it lets me)

Answer (score 1):

Tests if a parameter is present in the request

```
httpServletRequest.getParameter( "Y" ) == null
```

The following code tests the value of the parameter if it is present

```
if ( httpServletRequest.getParameter( "Y" ) != null )
{
    String value = httpServletRequest.getParameter( "Y" );

    // Put your test code here.  Include a empty value check
}
```

Comment: You should move the line `String value = httpServletRequest.getParameter( "Y" );` before the if-clause so the request doesn't have to be evaluated twice.

Comment: The code isn't intended to be a single block of code.  I'm only pointing out how to check whether a parameter is passed.  And then also how to use that to check the value of a parameter.

Comment: Oh I see, so requesting the parameter twice is more an didactic choice to show what to do with it; I agree, this makes the purpose of each line clearer.

Comment: @G.Bach +1 for the condescending sarcasm

Comment: @ScareCrow This was more than two years ago so I may be wrong, but I actually don't think I was being sarcastic. Doing superfluous stuff to elucidate something is sometimes a valid didactic approach.