# request getParameter is always null when using enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, validation, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am performing validation of inputted data such as email, password, name, etc. But I am already stuck on the first stage of validation which is to check if User entered nothing.

I already added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398374/java-servlet-validation-confused) but now it is always recognizing `email` as `null` and I can't forward to the login page in case of success (when email is not null).

---

### Code

signup.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="signup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="tonystark@mail.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

SignUpAction.java

```
public class SignUpAction implements Action {

@Override
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, DAOFactory dao)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String email = req.getParameter("email");

        if (email == null || email.isEmpty()) {
            return "signup";   // It loads signup page again (it works)
        }

        return "login";   // It should go to the login page (it doesn't work)
    }

}
```

Comment: You should tell us which framework you are using. Also, re-read that link that you posted. You don't want to use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Another error is this  type="email"  that should be type="text"

Comment: @rickz I am not using any Framework, just Serlvet & JSPs, running it on TomCat

Comment: @rickz why it is an error?

Comment: Fix those two errors.

Comment: @rickz It helped, appreciate your help. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: type="email"  is not strictly an error. But, you need to make sure your browser knows your page is HTML5.

Comment: Just accept @Perdomoff answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're planning to use your form for uploading a file, you don't need to specify the encoding type of  "multipart/form-data".

```
<form method="POST" action="signup">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="tonystark@mail.com">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The last paragraph in your link states:

"When using enctype="multipart/form-data", all parameters are encoded in the request body. That means that request.getParameter(...) will return null for all posted parameters then."

> Input type: email

Email is an html5 input type. [How To Use The New Email, URL, and Telephone Input Types](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-email-url-and-telephone-input-types.html#fbid=6eXlsv8IZFI).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a multipart/form-data (usually used for the puropose of uploading one/more file(s)) form the `request.getParameter()` method will always return `null`.

You can try

```
 <form method="POST" action="signup" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Or completely remove the `enctype` parameter.

Some references in another SO question.

[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)